# Iterate over XML with Python to join single element multiple times

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to extract data from an XML feed using minidom in Python and am struggling with one part.

My XML looks like this:

```
<step>
    <files>
        <file>
            <url>
            <subject>
        </file>
        <file>
            <url>
            <subject>
        </file>
        <file>
            <url>
            <subject>
        </file> 
    </files>
    <additionalData>
        <date>
    </additionalData>
</step>
```

The date element relates to all the files and I want my output to look like this:

- url subject date
- url subject date
- url subject date

but I only get one line in my output because I am only currently pulling back a single date:

```
publishDate = nodeDoc.getElementsByTagName("date")
    for dates in date:
        nodeDate = dates.firstChild.data
        publishDateList.append(str(nodeDate))
```

And then using a for loop to bring all my other pieces back at the end. Is there a way to bring back the date for each instance of a tag?

Comment: In `for` line you probably meant `publishDate` instead of `date`. And your XML is not structured like intended output. Try looping on `<step>` items pulling same `<date>` for each `<file>` children. Consider using [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with extensive features to extract granular items.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Still totally stumped with Python. Ending up using XQuery in SQL Server which did the trick.

Comment: Python can adequately handle your needs. Please post actual XML with date value for [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Python is a general purpose language and should not need to be replaced with a special purpose language like SQL Server's TSQL.